# how to fix: java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null at parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

[image]Crash report:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
0 java.io.Reader.<init> Reader.java:64
1 java.io.InputStreamReader.<init> InputStreamReader.java:122
2 java.io.InputStreamReader.<init> InputStreamReader.java:59
3 com.parse.ot.run PushConnection.java:693
```

I have 19 Occurrences with this crash. What I am doing wrong???

It is method, where I using parse quering from server. I think "e" is not null, but I don't know it exactly. Evereday I lose users for my app. Please help!

```
 public void preferenceFromParce(final AboutDialog aboutDialog, final MainActivity activity) {
        if (ServerAccess.isConnected()) {
            String key = "R" + getSHA1().replace(":", "");
            String objectName = PConst.getPreferenceObject();
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(key);
            query.getInBackground(objectName, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        TinyDB tinyDB = new TinyDB(App.getContext());
                        tinyDB.remove(PConst.PLANT_PREFERENCE);
                        new PlantPreference().savePreferences(object);
                        checkAppPresent(activity);
                        activity.selectVisibility(PConst.SETTINGS_FRAGMENT);
                        activity.selectItem(PConst.SETTINGS_FRAGMENT);
                        aboutDialog.dismiss();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(App.getContext(), App.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.update_error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        } else
            Toast.makeText(App.getContext(), App.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.no_connection), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I also using proguard with some rules:

```
-dontwarn com.parse.** 
-keep class com.parse.** { ; } 
-keep class com.splunk.mint.* { ; } 
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.* 
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
```

Comment: I also using proguard with rules:

    -dontwarn com.parse.**
    -keep class com.parse.** { *; }
    
    -keep class com.splunk.mint.** { *; }
    
    
    -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
    -keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }

Comment: The crash report won't help without knowing your code...

Answer (score 0):

it is a valid bug at parse. 
all desqriptions:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/863543397042016/

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1537874309831932/